# LateInitializationError: Field 'chatRoomStream' has not been initialized

Tags: firebase, flutter

The following code gives me the error:

> Exception caught by widgets library The following LateError was thrown building Conversations(dirty, state: _ConversationsState#77d8c):
> LateInitializationError: Field 'chatRoomStream' has not been initialized.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meet_up/screens/authenticate/helperfunctions.dart';
import 'package:meet_up/screens/home/conversationdm.dart';
import 'package:meet_up/screens/home/searchusers.dart';
import 'package:meet_up/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:meet_up/services/database.dart';
import 'package:meet_up/shared/constants.dart';

class Conversations extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ConversationsState createState() => _ConversationsState();
}

class _ConversationsState extends State<Conversations> {
  AuthService authService = AuthService();
  DatabaseServices databaseServices = DatabaseServices();

  late Stream chatRoomStream;

  Widget chatRoomList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: chatRoomStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: (snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot).docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ChatRoomTile(
                        (snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot)
                            .docs[index]["chatroomId"]
                            .toString()
                            .replaceAll("_", "")
                            .replaceAll(Constants.myName, ""),
                        ((snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot).docs[index]
                            ["chatroomId"]));
                  })
              : Container();
        });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserInfo();
    databaseServices.getChatRooms(Constants.myName).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        chatRoomStream = value;
      });
    });
  }

  getUserInfo() async {
    Constants.myName = (await HelperFunctions.getUserNameSharedPreference())!;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          'Conversations',
        ),
      ),
      body: chatRoomList(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF25D55F),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SearchScr(),
              ));
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.search),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChatRoomTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userName;
  final String chatRoomId;
  ChatRoomTile(this.userName, this.chatRoomId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => UserConversationDM(chatRoomId)));
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Color(0xff2d2828),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 16),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
              child: Text(
                "${userName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 8,
            ),
            Text(
              userName,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am really new to flutter, and a little bit of guidance will really be appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

late means you should initialize the late for the first time. but your code you did not initialize it. otherwise, go for without `late`.

From

```
late Stream chatRoomStream;
```

To

```
Stream chatRoomStream;
```

And check out this link more about
[lazy initialization](https://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2021/03/flutter-lazy-instantiation-with-the-late-keyword.html)